# Word /blog/ in slug post, problems in CPT. Solutions?

Tags: posts, slug, blog

I have a problem.

I need that in my posts the url slug will be /blog/ in single and categories.

If I change the permalinks in Dashboard I have problems with Custom Post Type 404.

Now I have this code, but it doesn´t work in categories.

I need /blog/first-post and /blog/name-category

Thank you

```
function create_new_url_querystring() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'blog/([^/]*)$',
        'index.php?name=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
    add_rewrite_tag('%blog%','([^/]*)');
}
add_action('init', 'create_new_url_querystring', 999 );

/**
Añadir la palabra blog antes de las urls sin que perjudique a los custom post type
 */
function append_query_string( $url, $post, $leavename ) {
    if ( $post->post_type == 'post' ) {     
        $url = home_url( user_trailingslashit( "blog/$post->post_name" ) );
    }
    return $url;
}
add_filter( 'post_link', 'append_query_string', 10, 3 );

/**
 * Redirect all posts to new url
 * If you get error 'Too many redirects' or 'Redirect loop', then delete everything below
 */
function redirect_old_urls() {
    if ( is_singular('post') ) {
        global $post;
        if ( strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/blog/') === false) {
           wp_redirect( home_url( user_trailingslashit( "blog/$post->post_name" ) ), 301 );
           exit();
        }
    }
}
add_filter( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_old_urls' );
```

Answer (score 0):

To Fix it, simply set with_front to false where the custom post types are registered:

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'portfolio', 'with_front' => false),
```

With this Custom post type will not get 404 error

Comment: Yes, I tried it, but Custom Post type still show 404.

Comment: Did you try or did you change the slug above according to yours ? Did you change  "portfolio" according to yours

Comment: $rewrite = array(
  'slug'                => _x( 'noticias', 'URL slug' ),
  'with_front'          => false,
  'pages'               => false,
  'feeds'               => false,